# Banco de Dados Modelagem

Tags: banco-de-dados, modelagem

Estou fazendo um modelagem para empresa e sou estagiário. Estudei muito no site que é em inglês... Quando acabei de fazer modelagem ai fui mostrar meu modelagem e dizem que estou fazendo algo errado e fiquei com estranho.

Modelagem:
Temos 300 celulares que são iguais modelo e fabricante (LG K4), 50 (SAMSUNG GALAXY J2) e grava dados (imei1, imei2, telefone1, telefone2, etc)

Esse é que eu fiz:

[image: List of layout]

E eles mudaram meu, ficou assim:
[image: List of layout2]
Segundo vai ter muito cadastrados.

Att,
Carlos Oliveira

Comment: Não entendi a cardinalidade de seus relacionamentos. Um fabricante aponta para um único celular? É isso mesmo?

Comment: A meu ver a sua modelagem está certa e a deles errada. Um celular deve pertencer a um modelo e este deve pertencer a um fabricante. O diagrama não mostra a cardinalidade e isso pode ser eventualmente melhorado. A modelagem fica mais precisa se considerar que os números de telefone são vinculados a SIM cards e estes aos celulares, o que sugere uma tabela separada para os SIM cards.

Comment: Pelo que entendi de sua representação de cardinalidade do relacionamento (a bolinha preta representa o lado N e o losango azul o lado 1) então o segundo modelo está claramente errado. Por exemplo, presume-se que um fabricante fabrique diversos celulares, como isto seria representado no modelo? Um fabricante teria múltiplas ID_FK_CELULAR, uma para cada aparelho?

Comment: @Piovezan: Exatamente, esse é modo que eu quero economia e mais rápido.

Comment: @anonimo Exatamente. Não gosto muito que teria múltiplas a toa, porque no servidor de nuvem tem apenas 40 GB de espaço.